# Encode Animated GIF to Base64

Tags: javascript, base64, animated-gif

I've been searching for a way to encode animated GIF's from a given URL to base64 without using external libraries like jquery (I will use it if absolutely necessary). I have [found results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/1220338) to encode static images to base64, but they all use the `canvas`, and `canvas.toDataURL()` will only encode a single frame of an animated GIF. Is there a way to encode animated GIF's (or any image for that matter) to base64 without using the `canvas`?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use [`FileReader.readAsDataURL()` <sub><sup>(example based on MDN web docs)</sup></sub>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) :

```js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var base64gif = reader.result; // your gif in base64 here
    preview.src = base64gif;
    document.getElementById('base64').innerHTML = base64gif;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
Upload your gif:<br/>
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br/>
<div id="base64" style="max-width: 200px; float: left; overflow-wrap: break-word;"></div>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Gif preview...">
```